# Lens that doesn't make faces look fat

Tags: lenses, interview

I'm using a "PANASONIC LUMIX G II Lens, 20mm, F1.7 ASPH" (MFT) lens to shoot interviews.

However, it distorts faces a bit when within 10 feet. I've read (after I bought it, unfortunately) that this lens isn't too well suited to interviews for that reason.

What would be a better fit? A wider lens would also be nice.

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: This question is better suited on http://photo.stackexchange.com/. Actually, it has been asked there numerous times and answered as well; see for instance [Which focal-length lens is usually used for portrait photography, and why?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/916/2236)

Comment: Another [complete comparison of shorter focal lengths](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/101811/37074) at Photo.SE.

Answer (score 2):

Typically recommended portrait lenses are around 85mm to 135m. These numbers refer to full frame cameras.

Since you are using a m43 camera with a crop factor of 2x you should investigate lenses from 40mm to 70mm that fit your Panasonic

Answer (score 1):

70mm to 100mm is the ideal portrait range. Although I prefer a farther throw many times simply for the look.

Wider will distort, longer will compress.

20mm, that's wide- very for full frame or even a crop sensor. Are you sure of that?

Comment: Thanks coinrocket, I'll investigate lenses in that range. Mine is a micro-four-thirds lens- I think 20mm is equivalent to 50mm.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used this lens but from my research it is a great lens for portraits/interviews. The Lumix 42.5mm F1.7 can be found on ebay for around $300 to $250 USD.